# I want to maintain order saved on categories or custom taxonomies terms selection at post edit screen in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to maintain order saved on categories or custom taxonomies terms selection at post edit screen in Wordpress

see image below: this is post edit screen in wp admin. I added man united first, and then barcelona, but saved the post it showed me aplhabet order, even in my theme, order is alphabet not custom order upon addition of terms.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA0A4.png

Comment: how are you displaying the category? are you using the_category() function or some custom query

Comment: I guess you get it wrong, kindly see my provided image above. I am talking about categorys/taxonomies terms in WP Post Edit screen, not in theme